# Model Selection: Goodness-of-Fit Statistic when Noise is Unknown (vs Reduced Chi-Squared)

Tags: bayesian, chi-squared-test, model-selection, goodness-of-fit

I have data D_k and different models M_i, and I would like to calculate a goodness-of-fit statistic for undertaking model comparison between the different M_i's, in the case of unknown uncertainties sigma_k on the data points in D_k.

**What is the best way to calculate a goodness-of-fit statistic (derived preferably in the most general/fully bayesian way) that can be used to select between models?**

For the case of known/measured uncertainties/noise/error bars/sigmas, in the general case I would usually compute the full posterior plus bayesian evidence - analytically or via MCMC/nested sampling - and use the Bayes factor for model selection.

Under the more restrictive assumptions of a gaussian, uncorrelated and unimodal posterior distribution I would maximize the likelihood and use a (reduced) chisq/chi-squared statistic, but this is usually a function of some known sigma_k.

Some helpful references:

1. De Sivia, Data Analysis: A Bayesian Tutorial, Section 3.5.1
2. McFadden, Statistical Tools, Chapters 6 and 7

(In particular, (1) implies use of a Student-t distribution rather than a chi-squared in this case - is there a meaningful equivalent of a "reduced" Student-t?)

Also:

3. Equation (31) of https://arxiv.org/pdf/1706.01629.pdf shows one potential route - "*the best fit line is simply the line that minimizes the sum of the squared perpendicular distances of points from the line*" - but (i) I need the value of the likelihood itself, including the prefactor, and (ii) the residuals d_i given in that case are a function of the gradient of the best-fit line, to which - unusually - I don't have access.

Comment: Why would be the purpose of attempting to 'reduce' it? What would you be trying to achieve?

Comment: I need a goodness-of-fit statistic that is independent of the number of data points. Does that help you with an answer to the main question?

Comment: @Glen_b - Also - I don't think it's unreasonable to seek a reduced version of the goodness-of-fit - the main point of the question is to establish the goodness-of-fit statistic, whether reduced or not.

Comment: The reduced chi-square isn't really "independent of the number of data points"; the mean is 1, but if the model is correct its average spread reduces with $n$